# Matlab freezes periodically

Tags: 16.04, permissions, hard-drive, filesystem, matlab

I have install MATLAB R2015a on Ubuntu 16.04 system. It is running ok with one mysterious problem. I am analyzing roughly 8000 DICOM files at different iterations. Every time I tried to type command in command window or script window it freezes temporally for few seconds then allow me to type and freezes and continuing.

MATLAB is installed in `usr\locals\MATLAB\R2015a` and my DICOM files are in Home directory. Initially I thought it is a hard drive problem but diagnostic seems ok. I executed `sudo hdparm -Tt/dav/sda1` to check the performances. Other programs work ok. I have installed ECLIPSE OXYGEN and it work fine, while reading external files. Normally the problem only appears once I open the directory which contain the DICOM files.

Can someone explain what is going on here, Is it a file permission problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely a permission problem with your files would trigger such a problem.

Please check the output of `dmesg` if there are any messages related to out-of-memory conditions.

Did you know Mathworks provide their own Q-and-A-site for matlab?, it's called "MATLAB Answers" and available under https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/

Perhaps you will get better support over there.